# java convert to utf-8 from postgres

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I'm generating html files whit this data (stored in postgres):

[image: my data in postgres]

The html files are generated as UTF-8, but the string looks like they appear in the DB.

[image: generated html file]

How I can do to make the text appear correctly? Like: ***Últiles de Escritorio***

Note. I'm not able to change postgres configuration, I'm using Java 1.6, Postgres 8.4, JDBC

*UPDATE:*

I use this code to create the html files:

```
public static void stringToFile (String file_name, String file_content) throws IOException {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file_name);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");

    try {
        try {
            writer.write(file_content);
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

And I use it like:

```
StringBuilder html_content = new StringBuilder();

ResultSet result_set = statement.executeQuery(sql_query);

while (result_set.next()) {
    html_content.append(String.format('<li>%s</li>', result_set.getString(1)));
}

Utils.stringToFile('thehtmlfile.html', html_content.toString());
```

*UPDATE: [SOLVED]*
This works for me:

```
new String(str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're sure that the error isn't happening before you add the string to the db.

Because you can't change your db settings, this isn't so easy to handle, first of all you have to know in which format the text will be saved in your db, see [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/multibyte.html).

Than you should be a familiar with UTF16 see [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2781.txt) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters).

Now, after you are familiar with codecs you wanna use, you have to create the correct utf16 value for each character you get from the db. I will just point out how it could work, the correct implementation you have to do by your own.

```
public char createUTF16char( char first, char second ) {
  char res = first;
  res = res << 8;
  res = res & (0x0F & second);
  return res;
}
```

This code should just combine the last 8bit of each char ( first and second ) to a new char.
Maybe this is the operation you need but it depends on the coding what is used on the server.

Sincerely

Comment: The data is already in the DB, I can't change it, just read it.
The DB properties says: _Encoding=UTF8_, _Collation=en_US.UTF-8_, _Character Type=en_US.UTF-8_.
If I will be able to change DB settings, what are your suggestions? Thanks

Comment: the problem is that java uses utf16. How are you creating the html file?

Comment: The file is created using UTF-8 (I think) (_I updated the code in the question_)

Comment: This code looks correct. Did you add this to your html file?
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> Without the browser doesn't use the correct encoding.

Comment: Yes I did. I'm not familiar with encodings but this work: new String(str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"). So I guess the data is stored as ISO-8859-1. Thank for your attention.